# DC-circuit with N-JFET transistor

Tags: dc, jfet

My task is to decide R<sub>D</sub> and R<sub>S</sub> in this circuit:

[image: Circuit]

The properties of the N-JFET are U<sub>p</sub> = -3.5V and I<sub>DSS</sub> = 10mA. The criteria here is that the operating point should give U<sub>DS</sub> = 7V and I<sub>D</sub> = 5 mA.

With U<sub>GS</sub> = -R<sub>s</sub>I<sub>D</sub> and the relation between I<sub>D</sub> and I<sub>DSS</sub>, I get R<sub>s</sub> = 1195Ω or 205Ω. I choose 205Ω, as it's the only option within the bounds of U<sub>p</sub>. U<sub>S</sub> = R<sub>S</sub>I<sub>D</sub> = 1V.

Knowing that U<sub>DS</sub> = 7V, I use KVL to find R<sub>D</sub>. Now I get (12V-7V-1V)/5mA = 795Ω.

My simulation is giving me I<sub>D</sub> = 4.29mA and U<sub>DS</sub> = 5.71V with these resistances, but the only parameter I can change for the N-JFET is U<sub>P</sub>(not the I<sub>DSS</sub>). This is making me believe that there might be an error in my calculations. Have I done it correctly, or is there something I missed?

Comment: Did the used FET exactly meet the mentioned criteria (Vp, Idss)? What means "not showing the same results"? 1% deviation or 50% ?

Comment: I updated the last paragraph with info from the simulation. The values aren't very far off, and I suspect that not being able to change I_DSS has an impact on the numbers.

Comment: I think, your calculation is correct - and the deviation from the simulation result comes from the Idss value.

Answer (score 1):

You're a little off on your calculations.
Vgs =/= -Rs * Id. Vs = Rs * Id. To find the gate Voltage, you need to know what the current draw into the gate is through that 1Mohm resistor is. Then Vg = Rg * Ig. Vgs is then just Vg-Vs.

Use that to solve for Rs and then Rd and I'm sure your simulation will be much closer to reality.